# Checkbox toggles Dropdown value (Acrobat JS)

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I am trying to create a Checkbox that you can toggle On/Off that controls the value of Dropdown List (variables Check1, Check2, Check3, Check4, Check5, Check6). The value set by the checkbox will be ✕ (x mark, U+2715) or if I toggle the Checkbox once again it will clear the Check1-6.

Is it possible/allowed at all to use *non-word* variables such as ✕ (U+2715)?

Comment: In PDF, the value of a checkbox is either the export value when checked, which could be anything, or "Off" when unchecked. The visual representation of the checkbox (the x mark you are referring to) is actually just an appearance that is stored in the field widget dictionary. The viewer determines what PDF drawing instructions will be used to create the appearance. Generally, the PDF authoring tool will create the appearances when the field is created but some viewers will modify them when the field value changes. Cont...

Comment: In short, the value of the checked field and what it looks like to the user may be completely different and the visual representation may be different in different viewers. So, you don't actually need to use U+2715 as the field value to make it look like ✕.

Comment: @joelgeraci thank you for your input, I can imagine I could even use a 'Button' instead of 'Checkbox' - the principle will be the same though.

Comment: Not quite. Buttons don't have a value so you can't do the comparison. However, you could set the button to function as a toggle.